# Possible to have speech only response?

Tags: dialogflow-es

When I do the following

```
conv.ask(new SimpleResponse({
            speech:voiceResponse
        }));
```

The audio response is played and the identical text is also displayed in the google assistant.

Only by providing text property that is an non empty string does it seem to override using the speech property as text as well.

Is there a way to eliminate the text altogether or is this by design/a bad practice?

Answer (score 0):

This is by design, and a bad practice to not show text if available. In general, you should show essentially the same thing that you are saying. Although there are good cases to show something different, you usually want them to at least be mostly the same.

If you feel you need to mask what is being said (if this is a spelling game, for example), it might make sense to omit the word or something along those lines, but you still should show something.